# Manipulating CSS with JS is not making any changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, responsive-design

I recently started in front end and am trying to make a responsive design.
I made a hamburger menu, translated it out of the page using css and I'm trying to animate it back in place using JS.
The console is not showing any errors yet there's no visible difference. What am I doing wrong?
here's the code:

```
const hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger");
const hamburger_menu = document.getElementById("hamburger_menu");
hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("pressed");
    hamburger_menu.style.transform='translateY(0%);';
});
```

Comment: Open dev tools and see if the styles actually change

Comment: They do not, I checked and the translate is still the same value.

Comment: A tip is to toggle a class instead of doing setting styles with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `;` from `'translateY(0%);'`

```js
const hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger");
const hamburger_menu = document.getElementById("hamburger_menu");
hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("pressed");
  hamburger_menu.style.transform = 'translateY(0%)';
});
```

```css
#hamburger {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}

#hamburger_menu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="hamburger"></div>
<div id="hamburger_menu"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, If I have any further questions should I ask here or open another thread?